# How to use reshape or other functions to fix this data

Tags: split, stata, reshape

I've got data that has combined the counties on some specific entries. Where each county should be a separate entry on this list, for these entries these have all been put on the same line. I've used `split` to separate these into `county1`, etc., but I'm trying to figure out how to use `reshape` or another function to keep all the data, but change `county`, `county1`, etc. into separate observations of `county`. I want to move from wide to long without losing the other entries.

```
utility_name                    state   county                          unique_id
Alaska Village Elec Coop, Inc   AK      Borough, Kodiak Island          221AK
Wolverine Pwr Supply Coop, Inc  MI      Allegan, Antim, Barry, Benzie,  20910MI
Wolverine Pwr Supply Coop, Inc  MI      Clinton, Eaton, Emmet, Gratiot  20910MI
Wolverine Pwr Supply Coop, Inc  MI      Grand Traverse, Ingham, Ionia   20910MI
Wolverine Pwr Supply Coop, Inc  MI      Isabella, Lake, Leelanau        20910MI
Wolverine Pwr Supply Coop, Inc  MI      Manistee, Mason, Mecosta,       20910MI
Wolverine Pwr Supply Coop, Inc  MI      Missaukee, Montcalm, Muskegon   20910MI
Wolverine Pwr Supply Coop, Inc  MI      Newaygo, Oceana, Osceola            20910MI
Wolverine Pwr Supply Coop, Inc  MI      Ottawa, Alpena, Charlevoix      20910MI
Soyland Power Coop Inc          IL      McDonough, McCoupin             40307IL
Soyland Power Coop Inc          IL      Menard, Morgan,Montgomery       40307IL
Soyland Power Coop Inc          IL      Sangamon,Schuyler,Scott,Pike        40307IL
```

This would then become

```
Alaska Village Elec Coop, Inc    AK Borough    221AK
Alaska Village Elec Coop, Inc    AK Kodiak Island    221AK
```

etc.

Comment: Can you say what problem you have with `reshape`? It seems the standard procedure applies after the `split`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
str40 utility_name str2 state   str40 county                      str15 unique_id
"Alaska Village Elec Coop, Inc"   "AK"      "Borough, Kodiak Island"          "221AK"
"Wolverine Pwr Supply Coop, Inc"  "MI"      "Allegan, Antim, Barry, Benzie,"  "20910MI"
end

split county, parse(",")
rename county origcounty

gen i = _n
reshape long county, i(i)
drop if missing(county)

order origcounty, last
list i - county
```

Comment: That does it perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to presuppose some knowledge of counties in the United States: a little more explanation would not go amiss in an international forum.

`reshape` is a command in Stata, not a function. But it need not apply here either way. You appear to want something like this.

As counties' names are separated by commas in one composite variable, the number of counties is the number of commas plus 1. We count commas by notionally removing them and finding the reduction in string length. Some of this code could be avoided had we sight of the whole dataset, which is probably impractical.

```
gen long id = _n 
gen ncounties = length(county) - length(subinstr(county, ",", "", .)) + 1 
expand ncounties 
bysort id : gen id2 = _n 
su ncounties, meanonly 
gen County2 = "" 
forval j = 1/`r(max)' { 
     replace County2 = county`j' if id2 == `j' 
}
```

In short, the main device is to use `expand` to replicate each observation, but the number of replications depends on how many counties are included in each.

Comment: The count `ncounties` needs to be adjusted for the cases in which there is a trailing comma (e.g. observation 2 of example data). It's not mentioned but I guess this solution presupposes the use of `split`. When used without the `generate()` option, it will create a `county2` variable, clashing with `gen county2 = ""`, so `county2` in the `gen` statement should be named something else,  `countyfinal`, for example. Would this be correct?

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Thanks for details. I've fixed to `County2`. This does assume prior use of `split` as in the question.